# Nw.js merge the zipped app.nw file into the NW.js executable

Tags: macos, node-webkit, nw.js

Is it possible to merge the zipped app.nw file into the NW.js executable on Mac platform.
Certainly is possible on Linux and Windows but doesn't seem to be the case of Mac.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the build of NW.js for Mac OS X [from GitHub](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js)
- Unzip the downloaded file, to create a folder contain nwjs.app
- Right-click on the nwjs.app and choose Show Package Contents from the contextual menu
- Navigate to nwjs.app/Content/Resources
- Place your app.nw file inside this Resources folder

[image: merge app.nw with nwjs.app on Mac]

- Modify the file at nwjs.app/Content/Info.plist so that `<key>CFBundleName</key>` is associated with `<string>NameOfYourChoice</string>`. (This defines the name of the application menu.)
- Rename the nwjs.app as *NameOfYourChoice*.app